# Is there a way to set a default "personalization" (window style, etc) in Windows 7 when accessing via Linux tsclient?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 machine at work and Ubuntu at home. From home I log into work (over a VPN) using Terminal Server Client (tsclient). But things are really slow with the style that's set on the work computer—Aero and everything. Things speed up dramatically when I set the style to "Windows Classic".

What I'd like to know is if there's a setting either on Windows or in tsclient (or if there's a different RDP client for Linux that would have this) so I can have the simpler style always set when accessing remotely, but nice shiny windows and everything when I'm actually at my desk at work.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I do know the windows and mac RDP clients allow you to disable theming and other bandwidth-hungry features (window contents while dragging, etc.), so it's certainly possible, its just up to the client to support it. tsclient is just a frontend for rdesktop, so you might check if rdesktop has new options to deal with this in case tsclient hasn't added them to its GUI yet. If there's no luck there, you might look into FreeNX, which supposedly also supports RDP and is popular with some of my friends.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that it's just a wrapper over rdesktop is a great lead. After playing around with that a bit it seems the main issue is that the mouse pointers are set to be Aero. Things get a lot better when I change them to anything else, but I seem to have to do that globally--I don't see an option in rdesktop for that.